# What's the best practice to synchronise channels and wait groups?

Tags: go

What's the best practice to synchronise wait groups and channels? I want to handle messages and block on a loop, and it appears that delegating the closing of the channel to another go routine seems to be a weird solution?

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    ch := make(chan string)

    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
    waitGroup.Add(1)
    go crawlTask(&waitGroup, ch, url, depth, fetcher)

    go func() {
        waitGroup.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    for message := range ch {
        // I want to handle the messages here
        fmt.Println(message)
    }
}

func crawlTask(waitGroup *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan string, url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    defer waitGroup.Done()

    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)

    if err != nil {
        ch <- err.Error()
        return
    }
    ch <- fmt.Sprintf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        waitGroup.Add(1)
        go crawlTask(waitGroup, ch, u, depth-1, fetcher)
    }
}
func main() {
    Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
}

// truncated from https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10 webCrawler
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to using a waitgroup and extra goroutine, you can use a **separate channel for ending goroutines**.

This is (also) idiomatic in Go. It involves *blocking using a `select` control group*.

So you'd have to `make` a new channel, typically with an empty struct as it's value (eg `closeChan := make(chan struct{})` which, when closed (`close(closeChan)`) would end the goroutine itself.

Instead of *ranging over a `chan`*, you can use a **select** to block until either fed data or closed.

The code in `Crawl` could look something like this:

```
for { // instead of ranging over a to-be closed chan
    select {
    case message := <-ch:
        // handle message
    case <-closeChan:
        break // exit goroutine, can use return instead
    }
}
```

And then in `crawlTask`, you could close the `closeChan` (passed in as another parameter, like `ch` when you return (I figure that's when you want the other goroutine to end, and stop handling messages?)

```
if depth <= 0 {
    close(closeChan)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a separate 'closer' go-routine prevents a deadlock.

If the wait/close operation were in the main go-routine before the for-range loop, it would never end, because all of the 'worker' go-routines would block in the absence of a receiver on the channel. And if it were placed in the main go-routine after the for-range loop, it would be unreachable, because the loop would block with no-one to close the channel.

This explanation was borrowed from 'The Go Programming Language' book (8.5 Looping in parallel).